# In csh, how to make "a/b" from "a/b/c/" using variable modifier?

Tags: variables, csh, modifier

When x contains directory name which contains / at the end, how can I remove the last path include the / pattern in csh?
Here is an example.

```
% set x=a/b/c
% echo $x:h
a/b
% set x=a/b/c/
% echo $x:h
a/b/c
```

So when x is "a/b/c/", I want to make "a/b". How can I do it using variable modifier? (in csh)

I'm also curious about how I can do that in bash. ${x%/*} will make "a/b/c" and ${x%%/*} will make "a".

ADD : of course I can pre-process the input file to remove / at the end , like sed -e '1,$s/\/$//g' file > file.1; \mv file.1 file' but I'm curious if it's possible with variable modifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture the output from [`dirname(1)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dirname.html) in whatever way `csh` does that:

```sh
$ dirname a/b/c
a/b
$ dirname a/b/c/
a/b
```

Comment: I see. then maybe I could use it in a script like "set y=\`dirname $x\`" and use $y.